# Laravel : querying sub relationships via models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Given that I have a Album, Category, Author and Role models :

- An Album have a Category and many Authors
- An Author have many Categories and many Albums
- An Author have many Roles for a given Album *(pivot "album_id")*

Here are the relationships :

```php
// Album.php
class Album extends Model
{
  public function category()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany(Category::class, 'albumable');
  }

  public function authors()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany(Author::class, 'albumable');
  }
}
```

```php
// Category.php
class Category extends Model
{
  public function albums()
  {
    return $this->morphToMany(Album::class, 'albumable');
  }

  public function authors()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class);
  }
}
```

```php
// Author.php
class Author extends Model
{
  public function albums()
  {
    return $this->morphToMany(Album::class, 'albumable');
  }

  public function categories()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
  }

  public function roles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('album_id');
  }  
}
```

```php
// Role.php
class Role extends Model
{
  public function authors()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class)->withPivot('album_id');
  }
}
```

For a given Author (route authors/id), I'd like to list all Album for that particular Author with it's Roles for the Album. The list has to be organized by Categories.
Something like that for example :

```
Author (id: 1)
John DOE

Category (id: 1)
  Album (id: 1)
    Roles (id: 1)
    Roles (id: 2)
  Album (id: 2)
      Roles (id: 5)
      Roles (id: 8)
      Roles (id: 12)

Category (id: 2)
  Album (id: 3)
    Roles (id: 1)
  Album (id: 4)
      Roles (id: 5)

...
```

With Eloquent relationships I managed to get "kinda" what I was looking for...

```php
// AuthorController.php
class AuthorController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $author = Author::where('id', '=', $id)->with([
          'categories.albums.authors' => function ($query) use ($id) {
              $query->where('id', '=', $id); // Only the current author
          },
          'categories.albums.authors.roles'
        ])
        ->get();

        return $author;
    }
}
```

But I struggle with the Author's Roles. I cannot get the Author's Role for a Album. It's all the Author's Roles that are retrieved for all Albums.

In my mind the problem is that I can't retrieve the link between the Author and the Album in the relation "categories.albums.authors.roles"...

Any help is much appreaciated ! :)

Comment: I guess you want to loop all the categories of the author and the display the books for each category with the role of the author for the specific book, but hear me out. Can you get all the books of the specific author and then from the Book model get the Category and the Roles? If the categories are not that much you can loop on PHP and arrange the results into array by category, maybe even group them with the collection function `group()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking about the same thing but with the disadvantage I'll have some logic in blade template :/. I was hoping for a "cleaner" way using Eloquent.

Comment: I think I'm quite there with the eager loading constraint but the problem is that  I don't know how to retrive the **$album_id ** in the relation `categories.albums.authors.roles`.

Comment: Then it will be possible to have something that should work :
`'categories.albums.authors.roles' => function ($query) use ($id) { $query->where('album_id', '=', $album_id); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want categories It's better if you start with categories:

```php
    $author = Author::find($id);
    $categories_related_to_author = 
    // get categories that has albums that has roloes that has our author.
    Category::whereHas('albums',function($query) use($id) { 
        return $query->whereHas('roles',function($query) use($id) {
               return $query->whereHas('authors',function($query) use($id) {
                    return $query->where('id',$id);
               });
         });
    })
    ->with([  
      'albums.roles.authors' // include albums and roles of their authors
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sorry, that's what I did by starting with Categorie down to Role (`'categories.albums.authors.roles'`).

Comment: By the way, the relation between Author and Role doesn't exists on Album

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention. The thing I ment is that with doesn't filter upon nested relationships, whereHas does filter using nested relationships.

Comment: Thanks, apparently [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) allows you to filter the query.
Now I tried to query the Collection model instead of Author like initially and I have the structure I wanted (collection > album > author > role).
But I'm still stuck with the role for an album :(

Comment: `'albums.authors.roles' => function ($query) use ($album_id) { $query->where('album_id', '=', $album_id); // How to get $album_id ? }`

Answer (score 0):

To precise, here's my **author_role** table

```
+-----------+---------+----------+
| author_id | role_id | album_id |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| 1         | 8       | 1        |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| 1         | 5       | 1        |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| 2         | 12      | 1        |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| 1         | 2       | 2        |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

And that's what I'd like to achieve :

```php
// AuthorController.php
class AuthorController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $author = Author::where('id', '=', $id)->with([
          'categories.albums.authors' => function ($query) use ($id) {
              $query->where('id', '=', $id); // Only the current author
          },
          'categories.albums.authors.roles' => function ($query) use ($album_id) {
              $query->where('album_id', '=', $album_id); // How to get $album_id ?
          }
        ])
        ->get();

        return $author;
    }
}
```

Finally `$author` should return something of the sort when visiting `/authors/1` :

```
Author (id: 1)
John DOE

Category (id: 1)
  Album (id: 1)
    Roles (id: 8)
    Roles (id: 5)
  Album (id: 2)
      Roles (id: 2)
```